# Need help about passing club_id in player controller

Tags: laravel

I'm making football blog and I want to make that i can create players, but i have problem with it because i get eroor "Call to a member function players() on null" i know where is problem but i dont know how to solve it, I have similar problem with comments and posts but i done it and now again same problem but it dont work

```
//PlayersController  
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
'fname' => 'required',
'lname' => 'required',
'age' => 'required',
'country' => 'required',
'position' => 'required',
'image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999',
'text' => 'required'

]);

//create Player

$player = new Player;
$player->fname = $request->input('fname');
$player->lname = $request->input('lname');
$player->age = $request->input('age');
$player->country = $request->input('country');
$player->position = $request->input('position');
$player->image = $fileNameToStore;
$player->text = $request->input('text');
$club = Club::find($request->get('club_id')); //problem
$club->players()->save($player); //problem
}

//club model

public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Player::class);    

}

//player model

public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Club::class);
}
```

Comment: It seems your club object is empty. what do you get if you `dd($request->club_id)`?

Comment: i get null when use dd()

Comment: then the problem is in your request object. check what you are sending from the form in `club_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `$club` is coming back `null` and that's why Laravel is giving an error when you try to use `players()` on it. Have you checked that `$request->get('club_id')` is giving you what you expect?

Also don't forget that your new `$player` doesn't fully exist yet in the database until you do `$player->save()`. Not sure if you can save it and also create its relationship to `$club` in one line. You could try saving it first, and then attaching it.

Comment: i save it on this way $club->players()->save($player); because when i try $players->save() it dont work to but in comments  $post = Post::find($request->get('post_id'));
        $post->comments()->save($comment); and it work fine

Comment: Hmm, well `$player->save()` should be working, that's the "normal" way to do it AFAIK, but that's separate from this issue though. `$club` being `null` is the problem here. Do `dd($request->get('club_id'))`. If that's null, then verify that `club_id` is getting sent in the request.

Comment: You can also check `$request->all()` to just view all the info at once and see if `club_id` is there somewhere or not.

Comment: i do dd($request->get('club_id')) and get null, i think maybe it's problem in view because i didn't in create view put hidden form and now i put it                             {{ Form::hidden('club_id',$player->club->id)}} but i get error Property [club] does not exist on this collection instance. and when i put only club->id i get Undefined variable: club